# Specific code from SAS to R

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to write this (SAS) comand in R. x is a variable with this specific format: j61915035t

x1 = trim(upcase(substr(x,1,1)));

I really appreciate what you are doing in this site!

Comment: it might be helpful to describe what the sas code does in words (for those of us who dont know sas). That said, perhaps, `?strtrim`, `?substr`, `?toupper` , `?trimws` *might* be useful

Comment: This takes the first character and makes it uppercase. Trim is probably redundant given it's after the SUBSTR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove leading/trailing blanks from a character string that is the uppercase first letter of the string x. So this should do it.

```
library(stringr)
x1 = str_trim(str_to_upper(str_sub(x,1,1)))
```

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU johnckane! I am an economist, but I am not so good in programming etc., but I am trying! Howevere I noticed that str_trim was not useful in my case (it gives the same result).

Comment: please have a look to this other command, I am sure it will take you 5 minutes max.:

Comment: please have a look to this other command, I am sure it will take you 5 minutes max.: if substr(x,1,2) in ('81','82','83') then y = '1';
else if substr(x,1,2) in ('84','85', '86') then y = '2';     I am creating a new variable y, which is based on x. If x starts with 81,82 or 83, y will be equal to 1 etc. this is a SAS code, I am trying to convert it in R.. many thanx @johnckane

Comment: y = ifelse(str_sub(x,1,2) %in% c('81','82','83'),1,ifelse(str_sub(x,1,2) %in% c('84','85','86'),2,NA))